# Use iPod Touch as Removable Drive

Tags: usb, ipod, ipod-touch, usb-flash-drive

Is there a way to enable disk usage on an 2nd generation iPod Touch without jail-breaking it?

Comment: i'd love to know this myself.

Comment: People voting to close, how is this off-topic for SU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I know of. However, I have been using Air Sharing for iPhone/iPod Touch. Just google "Air Sharing iPhone"

Answer (score 2):

How about drop box.  You can actually play music from the drop box folder.  Limited in size but it is free. There is a app in the app store to download to Itouch...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Diskaid](http://www.digidna.net/diskaid/) on a jailed, **non-jailbroken**; iPod Touch and read/write files from the Media partition. You will lose any data on the iPod if you use iTunes to update the OS or restore.

Comment: However, the original poster did ask for this without jailbreaking.

Comment: Doesn't he say "jailed"... meaning "not jail-broken"?

Comment: Diskaid doesn't require you to jail-break your iPhone/iPod

Comment: it's payware ($10 after 14-day trial), but you only need to jailbreak if you want to access the root of the drive.  it doesn't read music/video titles; use TuneAid (same company) for that.  i can't tell for sure but assume the "lose any data" bit refers to stuff you've written to the drive with DriveAid.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [Files](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=285578660&mt=8Modified=01ca4dc18bfef810) (iTunes link - $5) and it works great. I can wirelessly transfer my data to my iPod Touch. It has some impressive file viewer utilities too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using any app that has support for uploading files to it, but you'll have to have iTunes on both machines (source & destination).  For example, I used a free movie app called FlexPlayer.  I "upload" a sample .ISO file to it (in iTunes, under `Apps`, scroll to the area below where you can upload files to apps), then drag & drop it there.  After that, I go to target machine, open iTunes, go to same area as before, click on Flexplayer app, in the list of files select the file then choose "Save to..".

Answer (score 0):

you can use ifunbox

http://www.i-funbox.com/